# How can an object be visible both in main() and in a static library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries

How can I define an object so that it can be accessed both from the main() function and from a static library?

The object can be static (in my case it is a logger).

Comment: Put a declaration in a header and include it from both sets of code.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CarlNorum : But if I put the definition in the file that contains main(), it will never be seen by the library... (?)

Comment: Sure it would.  They all get linked together, right?  How do you think your `main()` function "sees" the code in your library?

Comment: Yes, they are linked together. I thought that being compiled as a library, it was "more isolated" and did not share objects like another source file in the same project.

Comment: Nope, nothing special happens just because something is in a library.

Comment: OK, I will try. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put a declaration of your object into a common header file shared by your main program and your library.  Then you can put its definition into one or the other, and when everything gets linked together later, it will all work as you expect.